# How to screw using the holes in this enclosure?

Tags: junction-box

I have this enclosure:

[image]

I wonder how I can connect some PCB (consider it as a plate where I drill holes) in to the holes from the enclosure (the 6 smaller holes in the bottom, where you can see 5 in the picture).

The holes do not have any screw thread. Should I drill through the enclosure housing to fix something using the hole? But it's a waterproof enclosure (and like to keep it that way). Or should I use screws which are a bit wide so they 'tighten' themselves in the holes?

How should I use these holess? 
This is my first DIM (do it myself) project using enclosures.

Comment: [Self Tapping Screws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-tapping_screw)

Comment: @brhans thanks (I tried one, but now the hole broke a bit, guess it was a little bit too big), but I try others. The hole I 'ruined' I'm not going to use anyway.

Comment: Yeah it has to be just the right size. The threads of the screw only need to cut into the plastic a little and the shaft of the screw should be smaller than the hole.

Comment: @brhans I understand, I'm going to search for the exact size and order them.

Comment: There are screws for this purpose.  They are sized for the hole and have a very coarse thread.  The screws cut their own thread in the hole when driven into plastic.

Comment: Thanks fixer1234 ... I found them, I think I need M4, so I will order them. Since I need my project fast, I just 'carefully' torn one hole but it still is tight enough. And I will leave a few holes for the good screws :-) Thanks for the help